# Not transfer/received voice (Twilio VOIP) after cellular call ended

Tags: twilio, avaudiosession, android-audiomanager, twilio-api, callkit

**iOS**

If I am on a Twilio video call (VOIP) and at the same time I received a cellular call on my device, I accept the call, speak with the person and end the call, I resume on Twilio video call everything is working apart from my voice is not getting transfer to the other end, also other end’s voice is not received at my end.

iOS is using **'TwilioVideo', '~> 1.2.1' SDK's**

**Android**

In Android, we are having a different issue, Audio is not getting transferred to a cellular call if the user is already on a Twilio VOIP call.

Android is using **build.gradle dependencies - compile 'com.twilio:video-android:1.2.0'**

So basically what I want to do is, even if I am on a Twilio VOIP call, I want the user to be able to successfully do a cellular call from the application in both the platform, Android, and iOS.

Comment: For anyone also with this question, this is being continued in a [GitHub issue over here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/issues/152).